# Call multiple functions using @onclick in Blazor web pages

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, blazor

Two functions in blazor component should be called when I click on the button. Tried with comma, semicolon and parenthesis. Nothing works.

```
  <div class="col-md-auto"><button type="button" class="btn btn-light btn-sm" @onclick="@SearchTable"@*call two methods SearchTable and SortTable*@>Search</button></div>
```

The two functions are given below

```
@functions{
    public void SearchTable()
    {
        foreach (KeyValuePair<int, SearchCriteria> entry in SearchCritRefs)
        {
            entry.Value.setSearchCriteria(entry.Key);
        }
    }

    public void SortTable()
    {
        foreach (KeyValuePair<int, SortCriteria> entry in SortCritRefs)
        {
            entry.Value.setSortCriteria(entry.Key);
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Did you try creating a single method to handle the click event, then having that method call SearchTable and SortTable for you?

Comment: That would work, but I just don't understand which I cant call two methods like in JavaScript which is pretty straightforward

Comment: I have no idea. I've barely worked with Blazor, so I don't know if what you're asking for is possible or not. I do know that *Blazor is not JavaScript* so there's no reason to expect them to be the same.

Comment: @pavan Sista - It's polite to accept the answer that answers your question i.e. enet below. Otherwise, the community stops answering your questions.  Reputation counts!

Comment: IMO, should accept @enet's answer since it answers your question and teaches the very valuable knowledge that using lambdas opens up a lot of options for you, but actually use mason's in practice.  When you're debugging, you don't want to have to scroll up to your markup to figure out multiple methods that you might have called, scroll back down to find them, and check each.

Comment: @ShaunCurtis, I did accept enet's answer after seeing it. BennyBoy1973, I am following the way that was first specified by mason in the comments, but I wanted to know how my question can be answered in Blazor, thanks for the explanation.

Comment: No problem and thanks.   Responders not only answer questions, we also get asked to review questions and answers.

Answer (score 16):

Do something like this:

```
<div class="col-md-auto"><button type="button" class="btn btn-light btn-sm"
    @onclick="@(() => { SearchTable(); SortTable(); })">Search</button></div>

<div>@message1</div>
<div>@message2</div>

@code{
    private string message1;
     private string message2;

   
    public void SearchTable()
    {
       message1 = "SearchTable";
    }

    public void SortTable()
    {
       message2 = "SortTable";
    }

}
```

Note: I've shown you how to call two methods when the click event is triggered as this is your question. If it is wise to code like that is something altogether different.

Answer (score 3):

I would adopt the approach of calling a single function which can then call as many subsequent functions as required.

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-light btn-sm" @onclick="@PerformSearch">Search</button>
```

```
@code{
    
    public void PerformSearch()
    {
        SearchTable();
        SortTable();
    }

    public void SearchTable()
    {
        foreach (KeyValuePair<int, SearchCriteria> entry in SearchCritRefs)
        {
            entry.Value.setSearchCriteria(entry.Key);
        }
    }

    public void SortTable()
    {
        foreach (KeyValuePair<int, SortCriteria> entry in SortCritRefs)
        {
            entry.Value.setSortCriteria(entry.Key);
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: I agree this is the cleaner way to do it.